# how to Access to a network shared folder from docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using Jenkins with docker, and I am looking to access a windows shared folder from my dockerNode. Is there a way, please?

Comment: if the docker node has a cifs / smb client, you could mount a volume on the node and share it with the container.

Comment: Thanks @DevLounge. i tried it and to mount it with cifs it required me to be root. unfortunatelly on my environment i could not.....so that why i am looking for a simplest way like  stage("Test") 
     { 
   sh """
    
   ls -l  \\server:\test
    
    """
     }

Comment: Yeah, on kubernetes worker nodes, the cifs plugin does mount the volumes as root, before attaching them to the pods :-/